# What happens after the events of All Star Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, continuity

I just finished watching this movie. Is there a follow up? Or was this a one off? How do the events of this movie fit into the main continuity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The Short Answer:

No, there is no follow-up to the All Star Superman movie. The events of this movie do not fit in any of the DC Universe continuities. It is a unique event having unique parameters in the creation of the character "All-Star Superman".

The DC Animated feature film All-Star Superman was based on the comic book series All-Star Superman. As noted in Wikipedia:

> All-Star Superman is a twelve-issue comic book series featuring
> Superman that ran from November 2005 to October 2008. The series was
> written by Grant Morrison, drawn by Frank Quitely, digitally inked by
> Jamie Grant and published by DC Comics. DC claimed that this series
> would "strip down the Man of Steel to his timeless, essential
> elements".
>
> The series was the second to be launched in 2005 under DC's All-Star
> imprint, the first being All Star Batman and Robin the Boy Wonder.
> **These series are attempts by DC to allow major comics creators a chance to tell stories showcasing these characters without being
> restricted by DC Universe continuity.** [emphasis mine]

With that said, the All Star Superman was not a single Superman but an amalgam or archetype of the iconic hero across his entire heritage encompassing all of his previous incarnations. This was done to allow a well known writer to try and expound on the legend of Superman unrestricted. Grant Morrison used elements from across the history of the character to create a single story that embodied every Age of Superman. All-Star Superman is not the canon character of Superman, he is the paragon of the archetype.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the follow up story is superman 1 million many many years later only in the comics.  15,000 years later superman emerges from the sun and is known as superman prime.

Comment: Hi, please don't post a new answer to modify a previous answer, instead you should edit the old answer.  You should take the [tour] to learn more about the site.